# Will steam try to 'claim' a game I didnt originally purchase via Steam?

Tags: steam, the-elder-scrolls-online

I am specifically interested in Elder Scrolls Online (ESO). I bought it via ESO, not Steam.  I have a friend that said he purchased another game via Steam and already had ESO on that computer and that he could not put ESO on his other computer because Steam wouldn't allow it.

I have ESO on 2 computers so I know they are not the trouble.  He knew he didn't authorize this.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you having the issue or your friend? This isn't very clear.

Answer (score 2):

Steam doesn't claim anything untill you activate the product via steam. However, the Elder Scrolls Online that was bought outside of steam CANNOT be activated on steam. I had bought ESO outside of steam (I was told I could activate it, but I couldn't), and had it installed twice at a certain moment because I got a steam key as well later.